# Mount local partition via fuse

Tags: linux, file-permissions, mount, fuse

I have a computer with Linux installed that is being used by several users. Included is a secondary data partition that is being shared between the users. But permissions are not easily handled. Anything created by a specific user, get's that user as owner. I was wondering if it would be possible to use fuse to some how mimic the way Android handled it's /data/media location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Android handles /data/media permissions and my solution does not involve FUSE, but if you create a group and add all users in it and set setgid bit on the root of the secondary file system and change it's group to group with all users then owner of each file will still be user that created the file but group of the file will contain all user and therefore they can access it if you set permissions on that file right (something like 660).

Comment: This seams to do the job just fine, even when creating something as root, the group is preserved. Thanks a lot.